# There's a way to link bars to a file in a chart bar in chart.js?

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

The title says it all: I'm using chart.js and I have a dynamic bar chart in my system and I need to open a report when I click on the bars. Is that possible?

HINT: the chart is an html5 canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31215847/360067. The only difference is that in your canvas.onclick, you use your `activeSector[0]` (say the label property) to force a file download.